# Explain this implementation of free from the K&R book

Tags: c

This is an excerpt from malloc/free implementation on K&R book. I am having great difficulty in understanding the free function, especially the if statement in the for loop: `if (p >= p->s.ptr && (bp > p || bp < p->s.ptr))`. If `p >= p->s.ptr` is true, then p must be the last node in the free list, since it is a circular list, now `p->s.ptr` must point to the base header (Remember therer is a list header defined `static Header base;`). So how can `bp < p->s.ptr` be true? Can somebody please explain it?

```
/* free: put block ap in free list */
void free(void *ap)
{
    Header *bp, *p;

    bp = (Header *)ap - 1;    /* point to block header */
    for (p = freep; !(bp > p && bp < p->s.ptr); p = p->s.ptr)
        if (p >= p->s.ptr && (bp > p || bp < p->s.ptr))
            break;  /* freed block at start or end of arena */

    if (bp + bp->s.size == p->s.ptr) {  /* join to upper nbr */
        bp->s.size += p->s.ptr->s.size;
        bp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr->s.ptr;
    } else
        bp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;
    if (p + p->s.size == bp) {          /* join to lower nbr */
        p->s.size += bp->s.size;
        p->s.ptr = bp->s.ptr;
    } else
        p->s.ptr = bp;
    freep = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is trying to find the free block just before the block that is about to be freed. It is only traversing through the blocks that have been freed, not all blocks.

There are two cases to consider.  Either the next free block comes after the current free block (the usual case), or the next block wraps back around to the beginning.

If the next free block comes after the current free block, then we need to check to see if the block we are freeing is between the current block and the next.  If, however, the next free block wraps around, then due to the circular nature of the list, we have to see whether the block we are freeing comes after the current block or before the next.

Note that the free list is the list of **free** blocks, so the `if` you are talking about is checking to see if the block that is about to be freed (but isn't freed yet!) is before the first block that **has** been freed, which is entirely possible.

Comment: Do you mean that when p >= p->s.ptr is true, p->s.ptr is another free block whose address is before p but is not the base node?

Comment: If so, where is the 'base' node gone? In my mind the free list is still a circular list with 'base' at the beginning and the last node pointing to 'base'.

Comment: Can you give a sample sequence of malloc/free that leads to such situation?

Comment: @Gurity: Once the base node has been allocated, it is no longer free, so it is not in the free list.